# Is there a Linq equivalent for creating collection from subset of an object used in a previous collection

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a Linq equivalent for the following piece of code where `Properties` is a list of properties in the object T and `entry` is an instance of T.

I find that I do code like this ever so often and I Was wondering if there was a more simple clear way to do this using linq.

```
List<Object> args = new List<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < Properties.Count; i++)
    args.Add(typeof(T).GetProperty(Properties[i]).GetValue(entry));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Properties.Select(t => typeof(T).GetProperty(t).GetValue(entry)).ToList();
```

now if you use often, just create an extension method (in a static helper class)

```
public static IList<object> GetValuesFor<T>(this IEnumerable<string> properties, T instance) {
   return properties.Select(t => typeof(T).GetProperty(t).GetValue(instance)).ToList();
}
```

and usage

```
var args = Properties.GetValuesFor(entry);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the equivalent, using the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:

```
var args = Properties
    .Select(p => typeof(T).GetProperty(p))
    .Select(p => p.GetValue(entry))
    .ToList();
```

You can of course have the whole `typeof(T).GetProperty(p).GetValue(entry)` part in one `Select` - I've split it for clarity. Note that it doesn't make much difference in terms of memory/performance - it won't create any additional collection in between, because LINQ is lazily evaluated, and it won't "run" until the `ToList` call.

Comment: You really don't need two selects...one is fine.

Comment: @Servy I find this more readable - one `Select` does one thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are transforming properties into values, which means that you can use the `Select` method:

```
var args = Properies.Select( p => typeof(T).GetProperty(p).GetValue(entry) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var args = Properties
           .Select(x=> typeof(T).GetProperty(x).GetValue(entry))
           .ToList();
```